# Populate columns based on other data, filter blanks

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am having a difficult time wording this except through an example:

Column A is a list of all names, columns F - L are possible tickets they may have purchased to attend a conference. They could have purchased a full pass, weekend only (including Friday), or one or more of Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, and/or Monday.  (I am including columns with unrelated data as this is automatically generated and it might impact the way this can be done).

| Names | Email | (other data) | (other data) | (other data) | FULL | WKND (Fri & Sat & Sun) | THURS | FRI | SAT | SUN | MON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sally | (sally email) | (other data) | (other data) | (other data) | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Jen | (jen email) | (other data) | (other data) | (other data) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Bob | (bob email) | (other data) | (other data) | (other data) |  | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  |
| Sook-Yin | (sook-yin email) | (other data) | (other data) | (other data) |  |  |  | 2 | 1 |  | 2 |
| Grace | (grace email) | (other data) | (other data) | (other data) |  |  | 2 |  | 1 |  | 2 |

*In another sheet*, I would like to create a list of attendance per day, ie Sally purchased 2 full passes so I would expect her and her guest to attend every day, etc. I must exclude people who are not attending at all (ie Jen).

| Name | Emails | THURS | FRI | SAT | SUN | MON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sally | (sally email) | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| Bob | (bob email) | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| Sook-Yin | (sook-yin email) |  | 2 | 1 |  | 2 |
| Grace | (grace email) | 2 |  | 1 |  | 2 |

I have tried FILTER and QUERY but so far have only stacked entire columns, including blank cells. I can't get it to link up with the corresponding names, and I'm starting to go cross-eyed. It seems like this shouldn't be that difficult but I'm not able to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Ω,byrow(H2:L,lambda(Σ,let(Γ,index(Σ,,1),Δ,offset(Γ,,-2),Ξ,offset(Γ,,-1),if(offset(Γ,,-7)="",,
            {offset(Γ,,-7,,2),
             if(len(Δ),{Δ,Δ,Δ,Δ,Δ},
             if(len(Ξ),{Γ,Ξ,Ξ,Ξ,index(Σ,,5)},Σ))}
)))),filter(Ω,byrow(Ω,lambda(z,sum(z)))<>0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I may have sinned by oversimplifying my example, imagining that I could adapt the answer - unfortunately this goes a bit over my head. In reality, my raw data contains 20 columns of (other data), I have last name and phone columns along with the Name and Email columns, and the day options also include Fri+Sun, Fri+ Sat, Sat+Sun, and Friday afternoon. I apologize. I'm not sure how to adapt your solution to fit that. I will provide a sample sheet in another comment, but I understand if this is too annoying being asked to solve it twice :(

Comment: [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cfwTn61RorJQMFxVPZyiwmErxwaVfKNhUrYGdaFa6x8/edit?usp=sharing) is a sample sheet with my actual raw data and desired outcome. Thank you very much for your help (again).

Comment: Updated the solution in your shared sheet. All the changes done are highlighted in `yellow`. 2 formulas in `results` tab and `one row` of manual entries done at the top of `Raw Data` tab

Comment: Wow outstanding!!! Thank you so much, I hugely appreciate the double effort you went to. This is exactly what I needed it to do. Again thank you so much.